# How to add scroll auto on overflow in case the parent as `fixed` position

Tags: javascript, html, css

I a trying to add the overflow auto with the children of the fixed element. but  not woks. what is the correct way to do this?

how to calculate the height as well?

```css
.parent{
  border:2px solid red;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

.content{
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>  
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


      </div>
    </div>
```

[Live Demo](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ilm7tdcGXOOpV1Kb?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add overflow: hidden on parent

```css
.parent {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that
    it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and
    a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need a pixel value for the height.

If you sent the .content height to say 100px then the scroll does indeed work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:auto;` from `.content` clas and add it to `.parent` class.

Like:

```
.parent {
  border:2px solid red;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
  overflow:auto;
}

.content {
  height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
  position: fixed;
  border:2px solid red;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:50%;
}

header {
 position: fixed;
 height: 80px;
}

.content{
  height: calc( 100% - 80px );
  overflow:auto;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>  
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var element = document.querySelectorAll(".parent")[0];
alert("The height of parent div is : "+element.offsetHeight+"px");
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.parent{
  height:172px;
}

header{
  border:2px solid red;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:80px;
}

.content{
  height:100%;
  margin-top:82px;
  overflow:auto;
  border:2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <header>
        <h1>Title</h1>  
      </header>
      <div class="content">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


      </div>
    </div>
```